# Eclipse C++ issue: No binary (but no compiler error), no classes (but no entry in the class hierarchy)

Tags: c++, eclipse, gcc, makefile

This issue is probably easily-solvable, but I have no idea how to do it.

Anyway, I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2 in Ubuntu 11.04.  I'm writing a game in C++ (not Java), and I'm writing several classes for it.  Fine.  I'm building frequently to check for errors.  Fine.

But my first problem is that when I hit Build (for both Debug and Release), even though the compilation dialog window appears I get no binary, nor do I get any errors.  This is what I get;

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Different-Game ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

That's it.  It's probably just a setting I screwed up somewhere, but I don't know what I'm doing here!

The second issue needs some explanation.  I had written up a class diagram in UML to provide a solid reference for myself.  I exported it as a .cpp file to see how it would work, and I forgot to remove it from my source folder.  That means my project thinks that these classes are part of the project.  Even after deleting the .cpp, it still thinks these classes are in.  They don't show in the hierarchy off to the left, but I can't create classes with the names they held (and should have given up).

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Are you manually creating your own make file?  If so, make sure you are including "make all" functionality as Eclipse seems to use that by default.

Comment: Nope.  I'm using Eclipse's automatically-generated makefile.  I didn't touch it directly.

Comment: Alright, the answer lies with including a make file.  It is a pain (for someone like me, used to Java/C#).  Read up on this webpage, as you'll need to copy and paste to create your own makefile. http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_makefile.htm

Comment: But the thing is, I had it working before.  I've managed to successfully load a class and open a rendering window (using several files, I might add).  So I don't see how making one from scratch is necessary.

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry.  I missed that.  I've had trouble with Eclipse and make files a good bit.  I have ended up using a Bash shell with Cygwin to actually run and compile my code and Eclipse to write it.  Not ideal, I know.  Sometimes you can have it "make" just one thing at a time by selecting it, right click build.  If you have nothing selected, it will attempt that "make all" command.

Comment: Do you have your source in a sub folder? CDT (the Eclipse C/C++ plugin) needs to be told explicitly about sub folders containing source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it CDT hasn't found anything to build. If it was only finding *some* stuff, it would kick up errors such as `undefined reference to 'main'`

There could be several causes:

- The file(s) could be omitted from the current build. Right click your source file, Resource Configuration->Exclude from build. Make sure nothing is ticked.
- The source files are in a sub-folder which Eclipse is not checking for source. Right click your folder, Properties, C/C++ Build make sure "Exclude resource from build" is NOT ticked.

You can verify which source files are being made by looking in your build folder (which is where CDT places generated makefiles). Look out for files titled `subdir.mk`. Each of these should mention the source files to be compiled in that directory.

E.g. if you have `~/workspace/myProject/src/main.c` then `~/workspace/myProject/Debug/src/subdir.mk` should also be there and it should contain a line with `../src/main.c`